# Using BuildContext as static parameter in App

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, static

I think to use BuildContext as static parameter in App but i never see someone to use it like that. That's why i am doubt to use it. Do you think is it bad idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context is not something that is constant in all app.It is changing in every page and every state of that page, so you can define it as static value.

Comment: i were thinking that was same buildcontext since runApp. Now i tested hashcode of context and itchange always. Thank you , i will search buildcontext better :)